# Determine the effective type of a literal in a comparison

Tags: c++, templates, macros, compiler-warnings

The following is a simplified version of a macro I have defined:

```
#define CHECK_EQ(a, b) do { if ((a) != (b)) abort(); } while (false)
```

which works but now I'd like to do additional work with the evaluated a/b values and would like to evaluate each only once. In other words, something like:

```
#define CHECK_EQ(a, b)          \
  do {                          \
    const auto a_eval = (a);    \
    const auto b_eval = (b);    \
    if (a_eval != b_eval) {     \
      /* Print a_eval/b_eval */ \
      abort();                  \
    }                           \
  } while (false)
```

but this breaks some current uses, triggering `-Wsign-compare` for e.g. `CHECK_EQ(some_unsigned, 1)`. What I would like is instead of `auto` to determine the type each side of the comparison will be converted to for the comparison. Hypothetical example:

```
#define CHECK_EQ(a, b)                                           \
  do {                                                           \
    using CmpType = CommonType<decltype(a), decltype(b)>::type;  \ What goes here??
    const CmpType a_eval = (a);                                  \
    const CmpType b_eval = (b);                                  \
    if (a_eval != b_eval) {                                      \
      /* Print a_eval & b_eval */                                \
      abort();                                                   \
    }                                                            \
  } while (false)
```

I suspect that's not quite right either since decltype(1) will be int. Is there any way to accomplish what I would like without modifying the existing `CHECK_EQ` calls or suppressing the warning?

Edit:
There seems to be a little bit of confusion around what should and shouldn't return a warning. Using `auto` returns a warning unnecessarily when one of the arguments is a positive *literal*, which is a valid unsigned literal as well (but `auto` results in a `signed`). In other words, ideally `CHECK_EQ(a, b)` would produce a warning if and only if `a == b` would. A second best solution would permit mixing types so long as the comparison ultimately performed is safe w.r.t. signed-ness of the types. This appears to be accomplished using `std::common_type`.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::common_type` ? Or maybe `decltype( a + b )` ?

Comment: The warning seems valid to me in this situation (that is, it is warning about a legitimate potential problem with the calling code). You should use the appropriate cast to ensure that `a` and `b` expressions are comparable when the macro is called, not within the macro itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(EDIT there is an alternative solution at the end)

## Solution 1 (original)

This never worked correctly, and will be incorrect both with CommonType and with `std:::common_type`. It was and will be incorrect since `~(0U) != -1` evaluates as false in such a scheme (assuming 2's complement), where you seem to expect it to return `true`.

I'd suggest using template functions:

```
// check if this is a simple int literal 
// such as 1, 0, 6789, but not 1U and neither expressions like -1.
template <class T1, class T2>
bool is_same(const T1& a, const T2&b)
{
   if (std::is_signed_v<T1> && !std::is_signed_v<T2>) {
       // some compilers might warn about the following,
       // in that case make it an "if constexpr" instead.
       if (a < 0) return false;
   }
   if (!std::is_signed_v<T1> && std::is_signed_v<T2>) {
       if (b < 0) return false;
   }
   std::common_type_t<T1, T2> a_common = a;
   std::common_type_t<T1, T2> b_common = b;
   return a == b;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
#define CHECK_EQ(a, b)                   \
  do {                                   \
    if (!is_same(a_eval, b_eval)) {      \
      /* Print a_eval & b_eval */        \
      abort();                           \
    }                                    \
  } while (false)
```

But if we are at it, why not just use template functions all the way?

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void check_eq(const T& a, const U& b)
{
   if (!is_same(a,b))
   {
       /* print a and b */
       abort();
   }
}
```

Note: If you have C++14 and not C++17, then replace `std::is_signed_v<T>` with `std::is_signed<T>::value`. If you have C++11 and not even C++14, then replace `std::common_type_t<T1, T2>` with `typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type`.

---

## Solution 2

After an edit to the question, it seems that there is a distinction between literal `int` and any other type of `int` value. The code should give the same warning as for `a == b` where `a == 1` won't warn if `a` is unsigned.

For that I introduce the macro IS_INT_LITERAL:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr bool is_int_str(const char (&str)[N])
{
    // TODO: deal with 0x1Dbef hex literals
    if (N < 2 || str[N-1] != '\0') return false;
    for (unsigned i=0 ; i < N-1 ; ++i)
        // NOTE: This is only 99.9% portable. It assumes that '0'..'9' chars are consecutive.
        //A more portable way would check (str[i] != '0 && str[i] != '1' ...)
        if (str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9') {
            if (i == 0) return false;
            // support 2ull , 1L, etc.
            if (str[i] !='U' && 
                 str[i] != 'L' &&
                 str[i] != 'u' &&     
                 str[i] != 'l' ) /* lower case L*/
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
}
#define IS_INT_LITERAL(x) is_int_str(#x)
```

The macro can then be used in the comparison function:

```
template <bool suppress_sign_warnings, class T1, class T2>
bool is_same(const T1 & a, const T2 & b)
{
    if constexpr (suppress_sign_warnings) {
        std::common_type_t<T1, T2> a_common = a, b_common = b;
        return a_common == b_common;
    } else {
        return a == b;
    }
}

#define CHECK_EQ(a, b)          \
  do {                          \
    const auto a_eval = (a);    \
    const auto b_eval = (b);    \
    constexpr bool any_literal = IS_INT_LITERAL(a) || IS_INT_LITERAL(b); \
    if (! is_same<any_literal>(a_eval, b_eval)) {     \
      /* Print a_eval/b_eval */ \
      abort();                  \
    }                           \
  } while (false)
```

This works without warnings:

```
CHECK_EQ(1, 1u); // like 1 == 1u
```

But this produces a warning:

```
void foo(int a, unsigned b = 1u)
{
   CHECK_EQ(a, b); // like a == b
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where does ~(0u) come from and why do you say I would expect it to be different than -1? Also, I was not familiar with common_type, I think that's all I need; what is the purpose of doing the is_signed checks instead of just skipping to the common_type_t part?

Comment: @Luis the question has `CHECK_EQ(some_unsigned, 1)`. 0u is an unsigned value of 0. So `~(0u)` is the max unsigned value. An unsigned value is positive, and mathematically different than all negative values such as `-1`. The compiler warms that the language makes a comparison which is mathematically incorrect, and that is what I'm trying to avoid in the answer. The answer tries to uphold mathematical correctness, the way other languages do automatically.

Comment: @Luis I have updated the answer according to your first alternative - treating int literals differently, and suppress warnings only for literals

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I guess doing exactly the equivalent of the literal `a == b` expression is not so easy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a templated function for the comparison?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
static inline bool _NotEqual(const T1& a, const T2& b)
{
  if (static_cast<T2>(static_cast<T1>(b)) == b) {
    return a != static_cast<T1>(b);
  } else {
    return static_cast<T2>(a) != b;
  }
}

#define CHECK_EQ(a, b)                                          \
  do {                                                          \
    const auto a_eval = (a);                                    \
    const auto b_eval = (b);                                    \
    if (_NotEqual(a_eval, b_eval)) {                            \
      std::cerr << a_eval <<" != "<< b_eval << std::endl;       \
      abort();                                                  \
    }                                                           \
  } while (false)

int main()
{
  CHECK_EQ(1U, 1);
  CHECK_EQ(2, 2.2);
}
```

Assuming `T1` and `T2` can static cast to each other.

EDIT:

With respect to the concern that `~(0U) == -1`, if it were *not* desired, then we probably should *not* have tried to discard the compiler warning in the first place. But `~(0U) == -1` isn't really a bad thing, e.g. there are quite a few cases where the standard library uses "-1" for an unsigned return.

Comment: Why keep using a macro? As the macro gets longer, the appropriateness of macro use gets smaller.

Comment: I'm just following the example of the original poster, trying to make the minimal changes to his original code.